# Extracting hashtags from twitter - string in R error

Tags: r, twitter

I have twitter data.  Using library(stringr) i have extracted all the weblinks.  However, when I try to do the same I am getting error.  The same code had worked some days ago.  The following is the code:

```
 library(stringr)
 hash <- "#[a-zA-Z0-9]{1, }"
 hashtag <- str_extract_all(travel$texts, hash)
```

The following is the error:

```
 Error in stri_extract_all_regex(string, pattern, simplify = simplify,  : 
   Error in {min,max} interval. (U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL)
```

I have re-installed stringr package....but doesn't help.

The code that I used for weblink is:

```
 pat1 <- "http://t.co/[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}"
 twitlink <- str_extract_all(travel$texts, pat1)
```

The reproduceable example is as follows:

```
 rtt <- structure(data.frame(texts = c("Review Anthem of the Seas Anthems      maiden voyage httptcoLPihj2sNEP #stevenewman", "#Job #Canada #Marlin Travel Agentagente de voyages Full Time in #St Catharines ON httptconMHNlDqv69", "Experience #Fiji amp #NewZealand like never before on a great 10night voyage 4033 pp departing Vancouver httptcolMvChSpaBT"), source = c("Twitter Web Client", "Catch a Job Canada", "Hootsuite"), tweet_time = c("2015-05-07 19:32:58", "2015-05-07 19:37:03", "2015-05-07 20:45:36")))
```

Comment: Could you provide some reproducible example

Comment: rtt <- structure(data.frame(texts = c("Review Anthem of the Seas Anthems maiden voyage httptcoLPihj2sNEP #stevenewman", "#Job #Canada #Marlin Travel Agentagente de voyages Full Time in #St Catharines ON httptconMHNlDqv69", "Experience #Fiji amp #NewZealand like never before on a great 10night voyage 4033 pp departing Vancouver httptcolMvChSpaBT"), 
               source = c("Twitter Web Client", "Catch a Job Canada", "Hootsuite"),
               tweet_time = c("2015-05-07 19:32:58", "2015-05-07 19:37:03", "2015-05-07 20:45:36")))

Comment: Please update this info in your post rather than in the comments

Comment: This worked for me `str_extract_all(rtt$texts, '#[A-Za-z0-9]{1,}')`

Comment: Tried...not working....couldn't understand....i have extracted this many times...same code...but even with the reproduceble example it isn't working

Comment: `str_extract_all(rtt$texts, '#[A-Za-z0-9]{1,}')[[1]]
#[1] "#stevenewman"`  I used `stringr_1.0.0`

Comment: DId you copy/pasted the same code as in the comment or your previous code with spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the whitespace in the `hash`:

```
 #Not working (look the whitespace after the comma)
 str_extract_all(rtt$texts,"#[a-zA-Z0-9]{1, }")
 #working
 str_extract_all(rtt$texts,"#[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}")
```

Comment: Many thanks nicola...it worked...though it seem quite strange!!!.....Thanks a ton Tyler Rinker....I will try qdapRegex shortly and share the results.

Comment: Why strange? You can't have the space in a quantifier: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy  This is typical behaior.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider usig the **qdapRegex** package that I maintain for this task.  It makes extracting urls and hash tags easy.  **qdapRegex** is a package that contains a bunch of canned regex and the uses the amazing **stringi** package as a backend to do the regex task.

```
rtt <- structure(data.frame(texts = c("Review Anthem of the Seas Anthems      maiden voyage httptcoLPihj2sNEP #stevenewman", "#Job #Canada #Marlin Travel Agentagente de voyages Full Time in #St Catharines ON httptconMHNlDqv69", "Experience #Fiji amp #NewZealand like never before on a great 10night voyage 4033 pp departing Vancouver httptcolMvChSpaBT"), source = c("Twitter Web Client", "Catch a Job Canada", "Hootsuite"), tweet_time = c("2015-05-07 19:32:58", "2015-05-07 19:37:03", "2015-05-07 20:45:36")))

library(qdapRegex)
## first combine the built in url + twitter regexes into a function
rm_twitter_n_url <- rm_(pattern=pastex("@rm_twitter_url", "@rm_url"), extract=TRUE)
rm_twitter_n_url(rtt$texts)

rm_hash(rtt$texts, extract=TRUE)
```

Giving the following output:

```
## > rm_twitter_n_url(rtt$texts)
## [[1]]
## [1] "httptcoLPihj2sNEP"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "httptconMHNlDqv69"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "httptcolMvChSpaBT"


## > rm_hash(rtt$texts, extract=TRUE)
## [[1]]
## [1] "#stevenewman"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "#Job"    "#Canada" "#Marlin" "#St"    
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "#Fiji"       "#NewZealand"
```